# Angular js with PHP response waiting issue

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, slim

I developed an API using php slim framework. Front end using angular js and build multiple asynchronous call for data collection. That for I am using angular js deferred and promise concept.

My exact problem is that, one api call is taking too much time for execution, but all other asynchronous calls are waiting for this completion. Whenever complete the longest execution call immediately get all other call response .

Is anything related to Apache server tuning or angular js deferred and promise issue ?
Please help me................

Comment: [`$q.all(promises)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) can chain them all at once

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need separate resolve state for each api call

Comment: you need to be more specific about how you want it to be resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue related to slim framework response object. I just write code for api call its working fine